# Facebook like button count resets on page refresh

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

As I click a like button, it posts it on the wall, increases the count, but when I revisit the page the count is reset to 0 (and I can reclick like for the same facebook account, but it does not post it on the wall one more time). Why is this happening ?

As relevant information
I needed more than one facebook buttons on the same page for different things, but wanted different descriptions so I used different href addresses for every button (www.site.com/page1.html, www.site.com/page2.html,etc) where I have different descriptions and they all redirect back to the main page (www.site.com), since this is where i have all the information.

Also, this works fine on Google Plus.

If anyone can help...
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, finally, I figured it out.

After running all URLs through the Facebook Linter countless times, only one button started counting ... the rest, still nothing.

What I did is change the "og:type" value on each page to "article" and run the urls through facebook debugger. Previously the type was set to a custom value and although Facebook says they support other values, this seems to have been my problem.

Comment: yeah, that worked for me, too. I had website for type, switched to article and voila, it worked :)